# center dollar values in siunitx S table column

Tags: tables, siunitx

How do I get `\$` values centered properly in this table?

[image]

This should be straightforward, but a frustrating search on this site and in `siunitx` documentation didn't help me.  Of course I can always put the units in the header row, as in the first column, but I'm curious.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cS[table-format=3.2]S[table-format=2.0]S[table-format=4.2]}
\toprule
Plan & {Phone cost (\$)} & {Monthly charge} & {Two year cost} \\
\midrule
Cricket Wireless & 499.99 & \$55 & \$1,819.99 \\
Virgin Mobile &  649 & \$30 & \$1,369 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you put `($)` in the header of all columns?

Comment: @egreg I could and I probably will but I'm curious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best thing is to add ($) to all headers: repeating $ in several cells is boring and dull.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{
  group-separator={,},
  group-four-digits,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{
  l
  S[table-format=3.2]
  S[table-format=2.0]
  S[table-format=4.2]
}
\toprule
Plan & {Phone cost} & {Monthly charge} & {Two year cost} \\
& {(\$)} & {(\$)} & {(\$)} \\
\midrule
Cricket Wireless & 499.99 & 55 & 1819.99 \\
Virgin Mobile &  649 & 30 & 1369 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Unrecommended way:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{
  group-separator={,},
  group-four-digits,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{
  l
  S[table-format=3.2]
  S[table-format=2.0,table-space-text-pre={\$}]
  S[table-format=4.2,table-space-text-pre={\$}]
}
\toprule
Plan & {Phone cost (\$)} & {Monthly charge} & {Two year cost} \\
\midrule
Cricket Wireless & 499.99 & {\$}55 & {\$}1819.99 \\
Virgin Mobile &  649 & {\$}30 & {\$}1369 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I appreciate both answers and will go with no boring and dull (and left justify the first column).